# How to pivot a table without PIVOT function?

Tags: sql, pivot, exasol

I have a table like:

| YEAR_WEEK | CHANNEL_A | CHANNEL_B | CHANNEL_C | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-11 | 40 | 10 | 5 | ... |
| 2022-12 | 50 | 20 | 6 | ... |
| 2022-13 | 60 | 30 | 7 | ... |

I need to pivot the data, so that the table is shown as:

| CHANNEL | 2022-11 | 2022-12 | 2022-13 | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CHANNEL_A | 40 | 50 | 60 | ... |
| CHANNEL_B | 10 | 20 | 30 | ... |
| CHANNEL_C | 5 | 6 | 7 | ... |

Problem is that my database has no PIVOT() function. I found this guide (https://docs.exasol.com/db/latest/migration_guides/oracle/execution/sqltranslationguidelines.htm), showing how to rebuild the PIVOT() function from Oracle in Exasol but I don't understand it nor can I successfully apply it to my table.

Comment: Check this answer out. There are method using aggregate functions or subqueries https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745042/efficiently-convert-rows-to-columns-in-sql-server/15745076#15745076

Comment: For the dynamic SQL solution: Exasol has no DECLARE. For the aggregate solution: Exasol returns "Feature not supported: VALUE". The JOIN solution - I don't know how many rows it will have. So no solution from that thread is useable sadly.

Comment: That's sad. Are there anywhere online playground for Exasol like db fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to rather transpose a table.

You may want to first build a subquery of the form (YEAR_WEEK, CHANNEL_LABEL, VALUE) using, say, UNION ALL and then do the pivoting via [Oracle to Exasol Migration](https://docs.exasol.com/db/latest/migration_guides/oracle/execution/sqltranslationguidelines.htm).